# Lazy loading or proxy pattern in my library

Tags: c#, reflection, proxy, loading, lazy-evaluation

Hi i'm writing a simple ORM DLL. The library works fine and i would like add some addone - Lazy Loading. 
But i don't know how to implements that. I have one proposition.

In my orm (i have creator but never mind) User should create DB class who implements IMapper and set mapper class.
Somethink linke this.

```
public class Person
{
  public virtual string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual int Age {get; set;}
}

public class DataBase : IMapper
{
  MapperSet<Person> Persons = new MapperSet<Person>();
}
```

If we have that class, and setup connectionString, we can take the data from DB. It's very similar to Entity Framework

```
Person p = Persons.Single(x=>x.Name == "John");
```

In that moment, i will check the all properties in mapping class and if are virtual then not return a that class, but Lazy Loading class.
I think out one conception. Not return (in that example) Person class but the class who extends Person class, and override all properties.

```
public class PersonReturn : Person
{
  //here i must create a method who really take the data from db
  private string Query = "SELECT TOP(1) FROM Person WHERE Name = 'John'";
  private Execute()
  {
    p = (Person)Db.TableToObject(Query);
  }
  Person p;

  public override string Name 
  {
   get
   {
     if(p == null)
      p = Execute();

    return p.Name;
   }
   set {}
   }

  //same
  public override int Age {get; set;}
}
```

User shouldn't see any change with using that class (only in debug it maybe see other class) it's should work as magic :P

My questions are :
1. How is implement Lazy Loading in for example Entity Framework, anybody know ?
2. Is simpler way from my proposition ? In my idea i must use TypeBuilder and Emit with IL source code - i hear it's problems with properties
they aren't be use in normaly way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Castle.DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) (same proxy that nhibernate uses)

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading is implemented by generating inheritor at runtime and override all methods.

```
public class A
{
    virtual protected string name { get; set; }
}

public interface IInterceptor
{
    object Invoke(MethodInfo method, params object[] arguments);
}

public sealed class AProxy : A
{
    static private readonly MethodInfo getname = typeof(A).GetProperty("name", ...).GetGetMethod(true);
    static private readonly MethodInfo setname = typeof(A).GetProperty("name", ...).GetSetMethod(true);

    private readonly IInterceptor interceptor;

    public AProxy(IInterceptor interceptor)
    {
        this.interceptor = interceptor;
    }

    override protected string name
    {
        get { return this.interceptor.Invoke(AProxy.getname); }
        set { this.interceptor.Invoke(AProxy.setname, value); }
    }
}
```

Proxy factory have to to

```
return new AProxy(custominterceptor);
```

custominterceptor must take id of your entity and in first usage instantiate A, query database to populate A and delegate call to A.

AProxy must be generated (postbuild or at runtime using TypeBuilder)